# MLE and CRLB with mismatched likelihoods

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, estimation-theory

Suppose that I can do a Karhunen-Loeve expansion of a log-likelihood function $p(\bf{x};\theta)$ into N terms and that these accounts for a fraction $1-\delta$ of the total energy. Now consider estimation of $\theta$ based on the expansion.

Two questions: 
1. Can I obtain a bound on the error of MLE based on the expansion to the true MLE?
2. Can I derive a new CRLB for the mismatched model?

Comment: I think that it is easy to observe what happens with the Fisher information (so as for the CRLB) when KL decomposition is used.